# Question on the solution to obtaining the truncation error for the Crank-Nicolson finite-difference scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I'm working on an exercise in a textbook that asks to derive the local truncation error for the Crank-Nicolson finite-difference scheme at the point $(ih, jk)$ for the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^{2}U}{\partial x^{2}}$. The text provides the solution, though one of outlined steps confuses me.

The solution begins by defining the truncation error for the particular scheme as: $$T_{i,j}= \frac{1}{k}(U_{i,j+1} - U_{i,j}) - \frac{1}{2h^2}(\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j+1}+\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j})$$

It omits some details for the subsequent parts, but what I assume the text does is it proceeds to rewrite the term $\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j}$ as $U_{i-1,j}-2U_{i,j}+U_{i+1,j}$. It then obviously performs a Taylor's series expansion for $U_{i-1,j}$ and $U_{i+1,j}$ and simplifies the expression, yielding:

$$\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j}=h^2 \frac{\partial^2 U}{ \partial x^2}+\frac{h^4}{12} \frac{\partial ^4U}{\partial x^4}+O(h^6)$$

My confusion stems for the following portion of the provided solution where the text *does not* rewrite the $\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j+1}$ as $U_{i-1,j+1}-2U_{i,j+1}+U_{i+1,j+1}$ and then uses the Taylor's expansion on the appropriate terms once again. It instead just uses Taylor's series on $\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j+1}$ without rewriting it at all, obtaining:

$$\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j+1}=\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j}+ k \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\delta^2_{x} U_{i,j}+O(k^2)$$

I'm unsure why it is that the $\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j+1}$ wasn't first re-written and then had Taylor's series applied as in the case with the $\delta^2_{x}U_{i,j}$ term.

Comment: Try doing it your way and compare to the way of the book. Was the result any different? Which way was easier?

Comment: @ekkilop Thanks for the response. I tried it the book's way as well as on my own using what I knew to see if I could answer my own question before posting on here, but I've yet to come up with any viable reason as to why it is the book has what's listed on the solution.

The book's method is certainly easier, the reasoning behind it still eludes me, however.

Comment: My guess is that the authors are driven by clarity and simplicity in their writing. It doesn't matter if you Taylor expand in space before time or the other way around - the result will be the same. It doesn't even matter if you expand $\delta_x^2 U_{i,j+1}$ in terms of $U_{i \pm 1,j+1}$ before you apply Taylors formula - the result will be the same. Therefore, in order to reduce the number of Taylor expansions and preserve as much clarity as possible, it is advisable to rewrite everything in terms of $\delta_x^2 U_{i,j}$ and then Taylor expand this quantity, which you only have to do once.

Comment: @ekkilop I must've made some mistake somewhere in my computations because both approaches didn't agree with each other when I worked them out. I was certain I did it correctly. Your advice is tremendous. Thank you very much.